# Google App Engine Connected Android (Eclipse) device endpoint error

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, endpoint, google-cloud-endpoints

I am just started exploring app engine with android (Java) and I followed a link to teach me how to create an  App Engine Connected Android Project. https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae

I followed exactly what was written in the link ,

1) Created a new app engine connected android project

2) Get the project number and API Keys from https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project

3) enable Google Cloud Messaging in the Google APIs Console

4) set the LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN to true in CloudEndpoints class

5) used a emulator with google api(v17)

6) installed the android cloud messaging library from android sdk manager

7) I am using eclipse indigo

i got errors these lines in RegisterActivity.java

```
import messageEndpoint.MessageEndpoint;
import messageEndpoint.CollectionResponseMessageData;
import messageEndpoint.MessageData;
```

i got i got errors these lines in GCMIntentService.java

```
import com.tez.deviceinfoendpoint.Deviceinfoendpoint;
import com.tez.deviceinfoendpoint.Deviceinfoendpoint.Builder;
import com.tez.deviceinfoendpoint.model.DeviceInfo;
```

and errors like that:

**Deviceinfoendpoint cannot be resolved to a type   GCMIntentService.java

MessageEndpoint cannot be resolved to a type    RegisterActivity.java**

What should i do?

Comment: did u use the @ApiMethod(name = String) on the methods in your endpoint before calling them in your Android Code.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the app engine project and select Google-->Generate Cloud End Point Client Library. Clean the project and refresh. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not quite sure about the cause of your error stack, it's encouraged to right-click on the app-engine project and select generate cloud end point as suggested above. However, if you badly need to create an endpoint on your own, you will have to make sure a similar entry as below is added into your web.xml inside your webapp directory.

```
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>${package}.MyEndpoint</param-value>
```

And after you ensure the above entry,

1. you can make your module
2. Deploy it local server and run the app on emulator

Or else if you're working with your production server,

1. Make the module
2. Deploy to app-engine and test it on a device or an emulator of your choice.

Hope this might help you if the issue was with your new endpoint/services exposed through the new endpoint that you create. Thanks!